# How to select only time from timestamp in mysql PDO select query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, pdo

As it currently stands the code below only prints out the complete time stamp as in "2016-03-31 13:22:06" but i would only like to select the time only so "13:22:06" or even just the "13:22".

Just wanted to know how to split these up within a PDO select statement to only grab the time.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM chatLogTwo";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
 print $row['time'] .' - '. $row['message'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with `date()` & `strtotime()` -

```
print date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['time'])) .' - '. $row['message'] . '<br />';
```

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) & [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Or change the query -

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%H:%i:%s') `time`, message FROM chatLogTwo"
```

[DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Absolutely spot on, wanted to know the different ways of executing the time only! Cheers for the quick response

Comment: Cheers!! Thanks fro reminding me about the party I am going to have.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(timecol,"%h:%i") AS time FROM chatLogTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can simply update your query into something like as

```
SELECT *,Date_format(`time`,'%H:%i') as only_time FROM chatLogTwo
```

and simply access it at your PHP code like as

```
echo $row['only_time'];
```